# Как можно сделать такой слайдер?

Tags: jquery, slider

[Вот слайдер:](http://themeforest.net/item/valeo-onepage-parallax-responsive-html5-template/full_screen_preview/6674091)

Хочу сделать такое. Не подскажете как? Тут вроде затухающий opacity стоит, а другой не могу вычислить. Не подскажете что там происходит?

Comment: никто не знает?

Comment: это owl Carousel, посмотрите какие там есть фильтры.